# Truecaller SDK Error : No compatible client available. Please change your scope

Tags: android

I am trying to implement truecaller in my app and i am doing exactly written in Truecaller Docs.
But still it gives me error.

I have tried googling the problem but still couldn't find the solution.

Here is the error:

`No compatible client available. Please change your scope`

Here is my code:

```js
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ITrueCallback {

  private ViewPager2 viewPager2;
  private List < Integer > imagesList;
  private Button btnContinue, btnLoginTruecaller;
  private EditText etPhone;
  private Preferences preferences;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Constants.removeStatusBar(this);

    TruecallerSdkScope trueScope = new TruecallerSdkScope.Builder(this, sdkCallback)
      .consentMode(TruecallerSdkScope.CONSENT_MODE_BOTTOMSHEET)
      .buttonColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
      .buttonTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
      .loginTextPrefix(TruecallerSdkScope.LOGIN_TEXT_PREFIX_TO_GET_STARTED)
      .loginTextSuffix(TruecallerSdkScope.LOGIN_TEXT_SUFFIX_PLEASE_VERIFY_MOBILE_NO)
      .ctaTextPrefix(TruecallerSdkScope.CTA_TEXT_PREFIX_USE)
      .buttonShapeOptions(TruecallerSdkScope.BUTTON_SHAPE_ROUNDED)
      .privacyPolicyUrl("<<YOUR_PRIVACY_POLICY_LINK>>")
      .termsOfServiceUrl("<<YOUR_PRIVACY_POLICY_LINK>>")
      .footerType(TruecallerSdkScope.FOOTER_TYPE_NONE)
      .consentTitleOption(TruecallerSdkScope.SDK_CONSENT_TITLE_LOG_IN)
      .sdkOptions(TruecallerSdkScope.SDK_OPTION_WITHOUT_OTP)
      .build();

    TruecallerSDK.init(trueScope);

    btnContinue = findViewById(R.id.btnContinue);
    etPhone = findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    btnLoginTruecaller = findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTruecaller);
    TruecallerSDK.getInstance().getUserProfile(this);


    btnLoginTruecaller.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {}
    });

    preferences = new Preferences(this);
    if (preferences.isLoggedin()) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      startActivity(intent);
    }

    imagesList = new ArrayList < > ();
    imagesList.add(R.drawable.black);
    imagesList.add(R.drawable.pubg);
    //        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this,imagesList);
    //        viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        preferences.setMobileNumber(etPhone.getText().toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OTPActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("phone", etPhone.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    });


  }

  private final ITrueCallback sdkCallback = new ITrueCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccessProfileShared(@NonNull TrueProfile trueProfile) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailureProfileShared(@NonNull TrueError trueError) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationRequired(TrueError trueError) {

    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onSuccessProfileShared(@NonNull TrueProfile trueProfile) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onFailureProfileShared(@NonNull TrueError trueError) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onVerificationRequired(TrueError trueError) {

  }
}
```

Here is the truecaller docs i am following:

https://docs.truecaller.com/truecaller-sdk/android/integrating-with-your-app/setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the above information.

The exception that you are facing :

**No compatible client available. Please change your scope**

comes only in the case where you are calling a method from TruecallerSDK that is not in the scope which you provide while initialising the SDK.

For instance, in case where Truecaller app is not installed or Truecaller app is installed but not logged and you have mentioned the sdkOptions as  TruecallerSdkScope.SDK_OPTION_WIHTOUT_OTP then on calling TruecallerSDK.getInstance().getUserProfile() method you will face this exception.

To refrain from facing this again you can put a check that if TruecallerSDK.getInstance.isUsable turns out to be True, then only call TruecallerSDK.getInstance.getUserProfile or you can change the sdkOptions scope to TruecallerSdkScope.SDK_OPTION_WITH_OTP to verify both Truecaller and Non-Truecaller users

In case if you face any queries in the future, please feel free to reach us via our support channel https://developer.truecaller.com/support for a faster and dedicated response.

Regard,

Parth